# How do I get user input from the keyboard in Python 2?

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

I wrote a function in Python which prompts the user to give two numbers and adds them.
It also prompts the user to enter a city and prints it. For some reason, when I run it in a shell, I get "name is not defined" after I enter the city.

```
def func_add(num1, num2):
   a = input("your city")
   print a
   return num1 + num2
```

Comment: Not really a duplicate of that (though it might be a duplicate of others), since it doesn't explain the difference between `raw_input` and `input` or that `raw_input` is specific to Python 2.

Answer (score 9):

If you're on Python 2, you need to use `raw_input`:

```
def func_add(num1, num2):

   a = raw_input("your city")
   print a
   return num1 + num2
```

`input` causes whatever you type to be evaluated as a Python expression, so you end up with

```
a = whatever_you_typed
```

So if there isn't a variable named `whatever_you_typed` you'll get a `NameError`.

With `raw_input` it just saves whatever you type in a string, so you end up with

```
a = 'whatever_you_typed'
```

which points `a` at that string, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
input()
```

executes (actually, evaluates) the expression like it was a code snippet, looking for an object with the name you typed, you should use

```
raw_input()
```

This is a security hazard, and since Python 3.x, input() behaves like raw_input(), which has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `raw_input`. `input` is like eval

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `raw_input()` instead. `input()` expects Python, which then gets `eval`ed.

Answer (score 0):

You want `raw_input`, not `input`.

```
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

As opposed to...

```
raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
    is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) asks for a Python expression (like `num1 + 2`) which is then evaluated. You want [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) which allows one to ask for arbitrary strings.